# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomField.php on line 1241

Tags: upgrade, error

I have started to get this error on a few contribution pages `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomField.php on line 1241`

I think it started when I upgraded from 5.25.x to 5.26 (now on 5.26.1).

Looking at the error message, log, and similar reports, I think I have tracked it down to a custom checkbox field that had a single option but no default value was set.

When I set a default value the error message disappeared.  When I unset the default the error didn't return though I am unsure if that is a permanent fix.

Just in case I have also upgraded to 5.26.2 and the error has not returned.

Comment: Question, I have the same error message. How did you find out which custom checkbox was causing the error?

Comment: It was down to a process of elimination, checking which profiles were used by the contribution page, and then what custom fields were being used in the profiles.  As it was an array error I narrowed it down to anything that could have had multiple values, which helped speed up the process and thankfully I didn't have may profiles or custom fields to go through.